# Using an Android SDK class in a custom annotation processor

Tags: java, android, annotations, annotation-processing, javapoet

I am trying to implement an annotation processor to fill views with a foreground color (nothing fancy for the moment). I have implemented my processor to process every Type annotation with my custom annotation. The process is going straight so far until I had to declare a variable inside a generated method with a type from Android SDK namely `ColorDrawable` the class generation is done successfully but there were missing an import for the Type `ColorDrawable.java`.

The problem is that since my processor is located inside a java library though I cannot reference `ColorDrawable.class` from there.

I am using the cool library `JavaPoet` to generate the java files. Is there any solution for this particular problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So after posting the same question to JavaPoet github repository I got the correct answer for this thread.

The trick is to call :

```
ClassName.get("android.graphics.drawable", "ColorDrawable")
```

The answer can be found [here](https://github.com/square/javapoet/issues/512#issuecomment-423352455)